# Saving an 8-bit grayscale image as a 2-bit image

Tags: images, image-format, file-format, bitmap, grayscale

Assuming there's an 8-bit grayscale image; what's the simplest method to save it as a "**2-bit per pixel**" image? Is it a **binary** image or something else (like a colormap image)? In the case of binary, what would happen to the second bit which will be useless, I guess.

Or it would be simply a 2-bit grayscale image? Does such a format even exist or is it only possible to use either binary format or 8-bit format for non-colored images?

Answer (score 3):

### 2 bit images

2 bit images are not 2 color images.

2 bits would store 4 colors. Currently the png file format allow several bit depths http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11IHDR.

Some good years ago the CGA color mode for monitors displayed a Cyan Magenta Black and White images. Those were 2 bit images.

[image: Test Drive game screen capture]

You could convert them to Red Green Black and Yellow. That was awesome!.

You can simulate a 2 bit image reducing a palette from an 8 bit image.

One technical issue I am not sure is if the current comercial software actually uses thoose bit depth or just use an 8 bit format with a croped palete.

### 1 bit images

This days the file formats can be 1 bit and jump to 8 bit images.

1 bit images are used all the time in a commercial print but as a part of a process. Your normal CMYK file or grayscale image is converted into a 1 bit image just before making the plates.

A image printed in a black and white laser printer can be considered also a 1 bit image at some point, for example.

And images for T-shirts for example, or cuted on vinyl, can also be 1 bit images. Think of the classic Che Guevara image.

### Conversion

There is no simple method. You need to make choices before converting it.

Here are some examples:

1) Base image

[image]

2) Linear conversion. This just makes from the 50% gray to white complete white and the rest pure black.

[image]

3) But you can control what do you want black or white playing with curves before conversion.

[image]

4) Dither. This kind of pattern are used in digital printers, inkjet printers and can be used in some high end commercial printing.

[image]

5) And this is the typical postscript pattern used in most commercial printing.
(I used a grayscale image after the B/N conversion so the image look better on screen.

[image]

Comment: Any indexed color format, Like PNG or Gif can do 2 bits. but like you i suspec OP means 1bit color

Comment: I'm reading some technical issues. Yeap It sems it is alowed 2 bit pixel on png formats. I'm editing a little the response. I'll post the reference.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the editing. :o) I´ll just change back the word bit, instead of byte. In color depth the correct unit is bit.

Comment: Nice answer Rafael!

Comment: @joojaa Do these formats refer to a table color in each pixel? So in my question the final image would be a 2-bit image **which has 2 bits in each pixel that refers to a 4-row color table**. Does the amount of table columns (# of bits) have a limitation in our example?

Comment: Thank Rafael, Some parts of your answer were useful for me. However, my question was more theoretical and about the memory usage of images; neither tools & softwares nor printing. So I wonder how does dithering do this 8-bit grayscale to 2-bit conversion in a mathematical way? Or about Linear conversion, as I asked in the question before, what would happen to 1 vacant bit of the 2-bit image, since blackwhite is a 1-bit image? Also could you please explain a little about "_B/N conversion_"? BTW Sorry for the late response.

Comment: @DummyBeginner yes indeed they do. usually they are limitted to max 256 color tables to avoid using more than one byte indexes

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop allows downsampling to an arbitrary number of colors -- but it will be saved in the image's native color mode (RGB, or at least as Indexed color).

The PNG file format allows 2-bit grayscale, and in Photoshop's Save For Web dialog you can set the maximum number of allowed colors. I'd have to test if Photoshop indeed creates a 2-bit grayscale, though, as it seems to prefer saving as a simple palettized image instead.

See also [How do I convert image to 2-bit per pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155092/how-do-i-convert-image-to-2-bit-per-pixel), which suggests [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org).